# Optimization of C++ program

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have the given program ? Can the output of the main function vary depending on the optimizer ?

1) Can the optimizer call the destructor of 'a' after the line# 19

2) At line# 17, Can this line be optimized away by any optimizer, since it not referenced anywhere in main ? or is it has any dependency on the static variable in the class ?

3) Again about line # 17, is it possible that the Optimizer initializes the array objects and destruct them straight away, because of 'b' is not used ?

```
 1.    class Test 
 2.    {
 3.        public:
 4.        static int n;
 5.        Test()
 6.        {
 7.            n++;
 8.        }
 9.        ~Test()
10.        {
11.            n--;
12.        }
13.    } 
14.    int main()
15.    { 
16.        Test a;
17.        Test b[5];                             
18.        Test *c = new Test;
19.        std::cout << a.n << std::endl;         
20.        delete c;
21.        std::cout << Test::n << std::endl;
22.        return 0;
23.    }
```

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy My focus was on the optimization topic.

Comment: But the compiler might have just eaten your cat.

Comment: @Thomas technically it is implementation defined  "It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters ... or with two parameters ... or in some other implementation-defined manner" `void main` is defined by the implementation.

Comment: ...and the consumption of one's cat is an example of implementation-defined manner.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy edited :) I just typed it up than copy pasting... and I didn't notice that

Comment: @Bathsheba well the implementation would be free to define that it eats your cat. Or it could decide to only define the signatures required by the standard, in which case it would be undefined behavior and the implementation would be allowed to eat your cat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimiser is allowed to do anything so long as (i) the standard is followed and (ii) there are no side effects in making the optimisation.

Since your destructor has a side effect (the decrement of `n`), then it must be called in the right place. In particular `a` must be destroyed after `c` is deleted.

Note that in production you'd want to use an *atomic* type for `n`: your code at present is not thread safe.

Also note that your declaration of `main` is incorrect. You must use `int main()` or the version with the command line arguments. Technically the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

Comment: "Technically the behavior of your program is undefined" can you explain me the reason ? is it because of the main method signature before ?

Comment: Indeed. You need `int main()`. Think about a low-level caller of `main()` that expects a return value on the stack. If it ain't there: **boom**.

Comment: @CodeWeed To elaborate on the side effects problem, note that we have things like `std::lock_guard`, which will release a mutex when destructed. It's common to use this class like `{ std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(some_mutex); /* code that depends on the mutex */ }`. `guard` is never even used after it is constructed, but the correct behavior of the program depends on it being destructed no sooner than it should be (at the end of the block in which it was defined).

Comment: @Bathsheba It is not clear how the objects in 'b' will be destructed! after the line # 20 ( if the optimizer chose to destruct ) ?